# Firewalld - allowing ICMP in custom zone (centos 7 / redhat 7)

Tags: firewall, redhat-enterprise-linux, centos-7

I want to enable ICMP echo-reply in a zone defined by source.

I have a zone MONITORING where I want to permit some services like mysql and echo-reply. Permiting services like mysql is simple, but I can't figure out how to enable echo-reply without using direct rules. Is it possible?

Main interface uses BLOCK zone, so packets are rejected with icmp-host-prohibited, when they don't fall to zone MONITORING.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Just to help those who have the same problem, I use the following command:

`firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT 0 -p icmp -s X.X.X.X -j ACCEPT`

it adds a rule that permits ICMP protocol if the source is X.X.X.X

Answer (score 3):

You can do that by allowing ICMP echo-reply in the MONITORING zone:

```
firewall-cmd --zone MONITORING --add-icmp-block echo-reply
firewall-cmd --zone MONITORING --add-icmp-block-inversion
```

That will work even if the main interface uses a zone rejecting ICMP packets as packets are matched by zones based on sources before zones based on interface. You can see that by looking at the INPUT iptables chain:

```
# iptables -nL INPUT
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
INPUT_direct  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
INPUT_ZONES  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me

Comment: An echo-reply ICMP packet is always a response to an echo-request ICMP packet. I just learned that echo-reply packets are considered as ESTABLISHED by iptables backend and are thus always allowed by firewalld. I think your problem is that you want to allow echo-request packets instead of echo-reply packets. If I am correct I will update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You may not want to enable *all* ICMP protocols, and you do not have to.

Add `--icmp-type 8` to only enable ICMP echo-reply.

The full command would be:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT 0 -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -s X.X.X.X -j ACCEPT
```